# Dropdown list filled with undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, dropdown

I have a stored procedure which gets data from the database and I populate a dropdown list with that data. The problems is, I have a lot of `undefined` values in the dropdown. The correct data comes back and is successfully inserted in the dropdown but somehow I have a lot of `undefined` rows inserted in the dropdown as well.

```
var url = window.rootUrl + 'DUP/GetAllStreets';
        $.getJSON(url, function (streets) {
            console.log("streets", streets)
            $("#streetNameID").append('<option></option>');
            $.each(streets, function (index, value) {
                $("#streetNameID").append('<option value="' + value.Ime_1251 + '">' + value.Ime_1251 + '</option>');
            });
        });
```

This is my function. I print the street out in the console, no undefined rows there. I am not sure what's causing this. Basically half of the rows are undefined
[image]

Comment: Are you sure all of them have ```value.Ime_1251``` set?

Comment: yup, double checked that :) @szczocik